# C# WPF - Write to Listview from any class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a UI in the MainWindow.xaml and in the window I have a ListView which I'd like to use for all logging.

How do I write to this ListView from any class without having to pass the window object the whole way through the system?

I've tried making a method in the MainWindow code behind called Log(string) and then accessing it from another class like MainWindow.Log("some text") but no joy!

Perhaps I'm just not entirely grasping the whole object oriented part of this problem :(

Help much appreciated!

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: if you are using MVVM, just pass the 'shared' ViewModel around to each applicable class that needs to do the logging. The ListView ill be bound to that shared ViewModel

Comment: See `MVC` or (popular with WPF folks) `MVVM`. It makes more sense to have a controller or controller-like object retrieve the data and populate the ListView with it. In WPF, typically this would actually be via some `data binding` (which you can also search for to learn more about).

Comment: Good help fellas, think my problem is that I'm trying to create a WPF program exactly like a windows form! Got any decent resources for 'sharing' my ViewModel (I assume this is my MainWindow?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using WPF ! So do not use any UI control type instances inside your back end language. 
Use data-binding, which WPF is mainly tailored to, to bind your list view to the instance of a back end class. And pass all around of your back-end an instance of that class .

The concrete basic implementation is not suitable for SO contest, but basic idea may look like

```
class Log {

   .....
   List<string> logData; 

   public List<string> LogData { //PROPERTY ACTUALLY BOUND TO LIST VIEW UI
        get {
            return logData;
        }         
   }

   public void AddLog(string s) {
         logData.Add(s);
         NotifyPropertyChanged(.. LogData  ..);
   }

}
```

after in some *shared space* of your code is created `Log log`. 
Anyone who will execute `AddLog`, will add the string to the lost of `log`, and raise an event to update UI.

For data binding examples may look on:

[A Very Simple Example of Data Binding in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319869/A-Very-Simple-Example-of-Data-Binding-in-WPF)

[Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

or just google for simpler or more suitable examples to you.

Comment: This actually makes sense, so in any additional class that I want to do logging from I would then create an instance of Log and use it to write to the LV? Sorry for the noob questions!

Comment: I believe that `List` should be `ObservableCollection`, otherwise the change notifications won't work.

Comment: @DavidC799 no the instance have to be one, so the collection of logs, of real strings, will be one. Just use the same instance among different types.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement simple binding in the following way:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Items}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then add your model class:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And use this model i.e. in your code behind. This is little hacky and should be moved to some Controller or something like that, but this is out of the scope of this question.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindowViewModel Model { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Model = new MainWindowViewModel();

        InitializeComponent();

        Model.Items.Add("one");
        Model.Items.Add("two");
    }
}
```

So we have View in xaml that is bounded to its "code behind" property called Model. This is why we have 'DataContext' property set in our . Then, we have our ViewModel that holds data for our View. In MVVM pattern we call it ViewModel. 
Of course you could also implement some ViewModel base and move there INotifyPropertyChange implementation but it's up to you. You can implement also implement MVVM pattern in any other way but core mechanisms are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post, definitely learned something.  Just this line is throwing me off a little: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` Why do we need this?

Comment: All controls, to make binding possible, needs to have DataContext (directly or by parent contrainer control) set properly. In my sample, we have set DataContext of the Window to its code behind class - MainWindow. Follow this link for more info about DataContext: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/

Answer (score 1):

You can access the MainWindow instance from everywhere in your application by `Application.Current.MainWindow`. It returns an object of type window so you have it to your main window class. Usually `MainWindow`. All together:

`(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).Log("some text")`.

Comment: This says that Application is not defined in the current context. I have the namespace in the using statements, am I missing something? :( EDIT: Added using System.Windows and it's compiling now, test time! Cheers.